# how many spores are needed to "infect" a wall?

Tags: microbiology, mycology

There's cardboard box in my room that used to be in another room that had mold all over the walls and it still smells moldy. This probably means the air in my room is polluted with mold spores.(right?)

If only a few spores stick to my wall could this "infect" the wall?

How many spores are actually needed to start infecting the walls in my room?

I threw that cardboard away, but I still wonder about the remaining spores

Comment: How big is this "wall" and what is it made of? Does it have a lot of moisture? There are multiple parameters here and hence your question is broad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the box likely had many fungal spores attached to it since it smelled “moldy”. This doesn’t mean that your room will definitely be contaminated because spores often wait for ideal conditions to germinate. There are fungal spores in the air we breathe all the time, so if those haven’t already colonized your wall then adding the ones from the box are unlikely to cause any problems.

If you do see spots appear, they can be easily removed with a damp paper towel, generic home cleaner, or diluted bleach.